# Using one else with multiple if statements in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

Is there a way to quickly check the following logic in C#?

```c#
if (a)
{

}
if (b)
{

}
if (c)
{

}
else //none of the above, execute if all above conditions are false
{
  /* do something only if !a && !b && !c  */
}
```

This differs from using `if-else` in that `a`, `b`, and `c` can all be true at once, so I can't stack them that way.

I want to run the else block when `a`, `b`, and `c` are all false without writing `if (!a && !b && !c)`. This is because the code can get quite messy when the if conditions become more complex. It requires rewriting a lot of code.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, *no*, `else` blocks only respect the `if` clause **immediately above them**, so you'll need an alternative.

This option isn't especially "clean", but I'd do:

```
bool noneAreTrue = true;
if(a)
{
    noneAreTrue = false;
}
if(b)
{
    noneAreTrue = false;
}
if(c)
{
    noneAreTrue = false;
}
if(noneAreTrue)
{
    //execute if all above conditions are false
}
```

Also, if your conditions are really pretty big, I recommend the rule G28 (Encapsulate Conditionals) from the book Clean Code from Robert C. Martin.

It is *pretty verbose*, but can be easier to read in some instances:

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    if(SomeComplexLogic())
    {
    }
    if(SomeMoreLogic())
    {
    }
    if(EvenMoreComplexLogic())
    {
    }
    if(NoComplexLogicApply())
    {
    }
}

private bool SomeComplexLogic(){
    return stuff;
}

private bool EvenMoreComplexLogic(){
    return moreStuff;
}

private bool EvenMoreComplexLogic(){
    return evenMoreStuff;
}

private bool NoComplexLogicApply(){
    return SomeComplexLogic() && EvenMoreComplexLogic() && EvenMoreComplexLogic();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about combine the concepts of Strategies and Specifications

```
var strategies = _availableStrategies.All(x => x.IsSatisfiedBy(value));
foreach (var strategy in strategies)
{
    strategy.Execute(context);
}
if (!strategies.Any()) {
    // run a different strategy
}
```

Comment: It's ok for complex situations but probably not with just 3 cases.

Comment: to quote the question "This is because the code can get quite messy when the if conditions become more complex. It requires rewriting a lot of code."  The other solutions are just ugly and don't help with maintainability.  You could also just use Func's and/or Actions instead of the solution I gave which might simplify the implementation

Comment: Yes, I like your solution and I think it's the cleanest, that's why I upvoted it. But to use it, you really need to be sure to have a complex scenario because all the work behind may not worth it in a simple situation. Maybe you could show in your answer an implementation of IStrategy.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than encapsulate some complex condition in a method that you will only ever call once or twice, I would just keep in a variable. This is also more readable than using some marker boolean as other answers suggest.

A contrived example,

```
bool isBlue = sky.Color == Colors.Blue;
bool containsOxygen = sky.Atoms.Contains("oxygen") && sky.Bonds.Type == Bond.Double;
bool canRain = sky.Abilities.Contains("rain");
if(isBlue)
{
}
if(containsOxygen)
{
}
if(canRain)
{
}
if(!isBlue && !containsOxygen && !canRain)
{
}
```

Now we have abstracted what might otherwise be complex conditions into readable English!