# Message Stating Value Exists In Array 2 AND Does not Exist

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

When I run this syntax my messagebox tells me that the value exists in array 2 **AND** I get a message stating the value does not exist.

What is causing both messages to show?  And how do I re-write to remedy this?

```
    string[] Arr1 = new string[] { "Game1", "Game2", "Game3" };
string[] Arr2 = new string[] { "Vid1", "Vid2", "Vid3" };
string[] Arr3 = new string[] { "Con1", "Con2", "Con3" };

string sVal = "Vid1";

if (Arr1.Any(x => x == sVal))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value Exists in Array 1");
}
if (Arr2.Any(x => x == sVal))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value Exists in Array 2");
}
if (Arr3.Any(x => x == sVal))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value Exists in Array 3");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value Does Not Exists in Any Array");
}
```

Comment: Tell us a bit about your data - could you have the same value in more than one of your arrays?

Comment: [Learn how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Related / maybe duplicate: [Using else with multiple if statements C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16952769) Although it depends on how exactly you want your code to behave.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger.. your code will always hit the Else statement for any of those conditions, if a condition is met, then return, otherwise learn how to construct a proper `if{}else{}` you need to revisit the C# Basics tutorials and focus on the `Conditional section`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] Arr1 = new string[] { "Game1", "Game2", "Game3" };
string[] Arr2 = new string[] { "Vid1", "Vid2", "Vid3" };
string[] Arr3 = new string[] { "Con1", "Con2", "Con3" };

string sVal = "Vid1";

bool in1 = Arr1.Contains(sVal);
bool in2 = Arr2.Contains(sVal);
bool in3 = Arr3.Contains(sVal);

if (!in1 && !in2 && !in3)
    MessageBox.Show("Value Does Not Exists in Any Array");
else
{
    if (in1)
        MessageBox.Show("Value Exists in Array 1");

    if (in2)
        MessageBox.Show("Value Exists in Array 2");

    if (in3)
        MessageBox.Show("Value Exists in Array 3");
}

// Output: Value Exists in Array 2
```

The last part of your code:

```
if (Arr3.Any(x => x == sVal))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value Exists in Array 3");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value Does Not Exists in Any Array");
}
```

is considered as a single `if statement`, in which:

- if the value is found in `Arr3`, then the message `"Value Exists in Array 3"`
- otherwise, if the value is not found in `Arr3`, then the message `"Value Does Not Exists in Any Array"` is displayed

Since `Arr3` doesn't contain `"Vid1"`, you will always end up receiving that message as the two other checks doesn't depend to the last one.

Answer (score -1):

Your is aren't properly joined. You need to write "else if" for every else apart from the first one.
Otherwise only the last if is connected to the else, while the other two ifs stand on their own and will print the message.

If a value can be in more than one array, you should add a bool variable and set that to true when one of the ifs is true.

Comment: re-word your answer, you state `Your is aren't properly joined` where you should state that the `if statements need to be changed to utilize if{{else{}` construct, your grammar is off this is my best guess, why the downvote.